# Change range withouth scaling in matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, range, axes

I have  a question, I am making a program that displays a zoomed area of Peru but the axis shown are in the range of the image (e.g. 7000x7500) but i want to be in UTM range (e.g. x-axis between 500000-600000 and y-axis 9500000-9700000)
I have tried using    `plt.set_xlim` and `plt.sety_lim` but no success, I think I have to use `plt.autoscale(False)` but it also didn't work or I used it wrong.

I create the figure and axes out of the main program

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
axe = f.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

this is the function I call everytime I want to plot

```
def plotear(self, mapa):

    axe.clear()
    axe.imshow(mapa, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
    axe.set_xlim(0,10000) #This is just for testing
    axe.set_ylim(0,10000) #This is just for testing
    plt.autoscale(False)
    self.canvas.draw()
```

---

Edit: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer worked as expected! Now I am having another problem, in the canvas I am showing the image, the x-axis and y-axis doesnt visualize correctly, here is an image [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbicF.jpg)
how could I fix it? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`imshow` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) you'd find that there is an argument `extent` which can be used to scale the image.

> `extent` : scalars (left, right, bottom, top), optional, default: None
>   The location, in data-coordinates, of the lower-left and upper-right corners. If None, the image is positioned such that the pixel centers fall on zero-based (row, column) indices.

In this case you'd use it like

```
ax.imshow(mapa, extent=[5e5, 6e5, 9.5e6, 9.7e6])
```

---

Answer to the edited question:
In the case of the image being too large, this is probably caused by you setting `axe = f.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])`. You should rather use `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)` and if the margins are not as you want then, setting `plt.subplots_adjust( ... )` with the respective spacings.