# What are the differences between add_axes and add_subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, figure, axes

In a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43283905) it was recommended to me to use `add_subplot` instead of `add_axes` to show axes correctly, but searching the documentation I couldn't understand when and why I should use either one of these functions.

Can anyone explain the differences?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

#### Common grounds

Both, [`add_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) and [`add_subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) add an axes to a figure. They both return a (subclass of a) `matplotlib.axes.Axes` object.

However, the mechanism which is used to add the axes differs substantially.

#### `add_axes`

The calling signature of [`add_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes)  is `add_axes(rect)`, where `rect` is a list `[x0, y0, width, height]` denoting the lower left point of the new axes in figure coodinates `(x0,y0)` and its width and height.  So the axes is positionned in absolute coordinates on the canvas. E.g.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
```

places a figure in the canvas that is exactly as large as the canvas itself.

#### `add_subplot`

The calling signature of  [`add_subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) does not directly provide the option to place the axes at a predefined position. It rather allows to specify where the axes should be situated according to a subplot grid. The usual and easiest way to specify this position is the 3 integer notation,

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(231)
```

In this example a new axes is created at the first position (`1`) on a grid of 2 rows and 3 columns. To produce only a single axes, `add_subplot(111)` would be used (First plot on a 1 by 1 subplot grid). (In newer matplotlib versions, `add_subplot()` without any arguments is possible as well.)

The advantage of this method is that matplotlib takes care of the exact positioning. By default `add_subplot(111)` would produce an axes positioned at `[0.125,0.11,0.775,0.77]` or similar, which already leaves enough space around the axes for the title and the (tick)labels. However, this position may also change depending on other elements in the plot, titles set, etc.
It can also be adjusted using `pyplot.subplots_adjust(...)` or `pyplot.tight_layout()`.

In most cases, `add_subplot` would be the prefered method to create axes for plots on a canvas. Only in cases where exact positioning matters, `add_axes` might be useful.

#### Example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (5,3)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(241)
fig.add_subplot(242)
ax = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax.set_title("subplots")

fig.add_axes([0.77,.3,.2,.6])
ax2 =fig.add_axes([0.67,.5,.2,.3])
fig.add_axes([0.6,.1,.35,.3])
ax2.set_title("random axes")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Alternative

The easiest way to obtain one or more subplots together with their handles is [`plt.subplots()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html). For one axes, use

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

or, if more subplots are needed,

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4)
```

#### The initial question

In the [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283643/change-range-withouth-scaling-in-matplot?noredirect=1&lq=1) an axes was placed using `fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])`, such that it sits tight to the figure boundaries. The disadvantage of this is of course that ticks, ticklabels, axes labels and titles are cut off. Therefore I suggested in one of the comments to the answer to use `fig.add_subplot` as this will automatically allow for enough space for those elements, and, if this is not enough, can be adjusted using `pyplot.subplots_adjust(...)` or `pyplot.tight_layout()`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317) is great.
Yet in that context usually one want to generate an axes for a plot and `add_axes()` has too much overhead.

So one trick is, as in the answer of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, is to use `add_subplot(111)`.
Yet more elegant alternative and simple would be:

```py
hAx = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10)).gca()
```

If you want `3D` projection you can pass any axes property. For instance the `projection`:

```py
hAx = plt.figure(figsize = (16, 10)).gca(projection = '3d')
```