# Subplot in a non-grid constellation in python / Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I wonder if there's the possibility to display several plots or images in a non-grid constellation ? For example is there a way to display a set of images in one figure in a circular constellation along the perimeter using Matplotlib or any other python package alike ?

Answer (score 1):

An axes can be created and positionned via `fig.add_axes([x,y,width,height])` see [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes). Also see [What are the differences between add_axes and add_subplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326680/what-are-the-differences-between-add-axes-and-add-subplot)

In this case we can add the axes to positions lying on a circle, creating some kind of manual radial grid of axes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 8
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
r = 0.37
h = 0.9 - 2*r
w = h
X,Y = r*np.cos(t)-w/2.+ 0.5, r*np.sin(t)-h/2.+ 0.5

fig = plt.figure()
axes = []
for x,y in zip(X,Y):
    axes.append(fig.add_axes([x, y, w, h]))

plt.show()
```

[image]