# What does left and bottom in figure.add_axes() do in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

Hello, I am currently learning matplotlib. I have just learnt about figures and the `add_axes()` method. For the `add_axes()` method, you pass in a list containing `[left, bottom, width, height]`.

Obviously, `width` and `height` controls the width and height of the graph, but what does `left` and `bottom` do?

Here is my `add_axes()` -> `axes = figure.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6])`

I keep changing `left` and `bottom`, but nothing on the plot is changing. I read the matplotlib documentation on `figure.add_axes()`, but it did not explain what `left` and `bottom` did.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description and example of mpl.figure.add_axes

```
mpl.figure.add_axes(rect, projection=None, polar=False, **kwargs)
```

Adds an axis to the current figure or a specified axis.
From the [matplotlib mpl.figure.ad_axes method documentation:](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes)
rect: sequence of floats. The dimensions [left, bottom, width, height] of the new Axes. All quantities are in fractions of figure width and height.

- left = how far from the left of the figure (like a x value)
- bottom = how far from the bottom of the figure (like a y value)

[Here is a quick google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326680/what-are-the-differences-between-add-axes-and-add-subplot)
Here is an example:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.575,0.55,0.3,0.3])

ax1.grid(axis='y', dashes=(8,3), color='gray', alpha=0.3)
for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    [ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top','right']]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1 question though. You say `left` and `bottom` are how far from the left and bottom of the figure. But what is the thing that is that much away from the figure? Like, `bottom and left define how far ? is away from the figure `

Comment: All quantities are in fractions of figure width and height.